# How to resolve wwwroot paths in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to edit the contents of wwwroot at runtime, how could `~/wwwroot` be mapped (is there some utility like `VirtualPathUtility`)?

`VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/wwwroot")` doesn't work (expected)

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()`?

Comment: System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/wwwroot"); ?

Comment: `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/wwwroot");` gives `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First inject `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment` in constructor of your controller then use `MapPath` method like this:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public FooController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment= hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Bar()
    {
        // this maps to /wwwroot folder
        var wwwroot = _hostingEnvironment.MapPath("");

        // this maps to /wwwroot/someFolder
        var someFolder=_hostingEnvironment.MapPath("someFolder");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: `IHostingEnvironment` was what I was missing, thanks!